# "I'll never pray to a God since my butt issues"

Tags: grammar, prepositions, american-english, prepositional-phrases, subordinate-clauses

> - [I'll never pray to a God **since my butt issues.**](https://youtu.be/suv-lZ7pAOk?t=104)

The usage of *'since'* drew my attention and puzzled me. I don't understand why it was used here and whether it was a substitute for either *'because of'* or *'as a result of'*.

The alternatives I can think of are:

> *[giving a reason]*
>
> - I'll never pray to a God since I have my butt issues.
> - I'll never pray to a God because of my butt issues.
> - I'll never pray to a God because I've got my butt issues.

One more option could be

> *[describing a particular time in the past]*
>
> - <strike>I'll never pray to a God since my butt issues kicked in.</strike> (=happened, started progressing)

but I discarded it because the sentence conveys the future while we actually mean something like

> - I haven't prayed to a God since my butt issues kicked in.
> - I haven't been praying to a God since my butt issues kicked in.

I always thought we need a subordinate clause after *'since'* when we are giving a reason. Otherwise, it should be a date, a time or a noun phrase which would refer back to a previous point in time.

**Can we put a noun phrase after *'since'*?** And more specifically, **is a noun phrase acceptable after *'since'* to give a reason?**

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: First, you should tell us where you got this. Second, spoken AmE is very loose. He means: since [I have had] my butt issues. Eliding stuff is very common in AmE speech. It is very common to see no verbs after since in this type of speech.

Comment: @Lambie the first quote has a link

Comment: OK, sorry. My comment is unchanged, though. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That use of **since** is idiomatic.

> I haven't been able to walk since *my surgery*.
>
> I haven't had much of an appetite since *my bout with the flu*.
>
> I haven't been able to drive since *my dizziness*.

The noun-phrase has to refer to something that either marks an event or  has an onset that can serve as a point-in-time.

The first two examples are of an event which has taken place and come to an end. The event serves as the reference time.

The last example would be understood to mean "ever since I've had this dizziness" if it was said in a conversation where the speaker was discussing the condition.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be a mistake.  A man is being interviewed about his nighttime routine, but he has to give the answers from three other guys. They are making him say odd and embarrassing things.

So they tell him to say weird things like "Say hey to baby Jesus".  The interviewing guy asks if he means "say a prayer".  The controllers tell the man to say "I don't pray since my butt issue" meaning both "I don't pray because of the problem I have with my butt" and "I haven't prayed from the time when I started having problems with my butt".  This is an embarrassing thing to say to an interviewer.

But the person being interviewed makes a mistake.  He says "I'll never pray to a god since my butt issue"  In changing part of the sentence he has got the grammar wrong.  It is not surprising to make a mistake like this in an unnatural situation like in the video.

Comment: He has to give answers **to** three other guys. "since my butt issue" is short for the proper "since I've had my butt issue" and typical "American-speak".